# Android: Problems with ActionBar Customization

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme

I've just now started to learn Android Development on my own and I'm facing a problem and I need help.

I'm learning about `ActionBar`. I was interested to customize the `ActionBar`.

The steps I've followed to change its background color and the spacing of the items are:

1. The idea was to have a base theme with an `ActionBar`. Then customize it. The code:

   ```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
   </style>

   <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
       <item name="android:background">#F44336</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Next, in my `AndroidManifest.xml` I use the custom theme I've created. The code:

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

**But the color of my `ActionBar` is still black. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport. To set the color of the action bar, use `colorPrimary`, not `android:background`, in your theme.

For example, this theme sets the three major color tints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

This particular sample happens to define the color values themselves via color resources, in a `res/values/colors.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#3f51b5</color>
  <color name="primary_dark">#1a237e</color>
  <color name="accent">#ffee58</color>
</resources>
```

An activity that uses the custom theme then gets the primary color as the action bar background:

[image: appcompat-v7 Sample]

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/Basic/Switch))

Comment: Thank you. I still have a question. This will help me to control the color, but how can I control other attributes of the ActionBar. Such as the distance between icons?

Comment: @HaggarTheHorrible: Ideally, you leave the distance between the icons alone. Beyond that, though, "other attributes" are controlled either by theme settings or by calls on the `ActionBar` that you get from `getSupportActionBar()`.